# How to explain repeating words for different subjects

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Suppose I have numbers, letters and names. Suppose further that I would like to store them in matrices, a matrix for each. Then, how could I explain this in a correct English sentence?

> The numbers, the letters and the names are stored in their own matrices, a
>   matrix for each.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers, letters and names are each stored in their own separate matrix.

or

The numbers, letters, and names are each stored in a separate matrix.

Comment: Or simply, "The numbers, letters, and names are each stored in a separate matrix."

Comment: @Mixolydian, yes.  Updated the answer.