# Can I use the word each twice in my sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I have a mixture of two subjects. I can call each of them as a mixture component. I would like to store each mixture component in its own matrix.

From my old question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/196276/how-to-explain-repeating-words-for-different-subjects), I may write my sentence as follows:

> The numbers, letters, and mixture components are each stored in a separate matrix.

This may make the reader think that I stored my mixture components in one matrix, which is incorrect. Therefore, I would like to clarify my sentence even further.

> The numbers, letters, and (each) mixture component are each stored in a separate matrix.

I just wonder if this correct? or I must not use `each` twice in my sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The best way might be:

> The numbers, letters, and every mixture component are stored in separate matrices.

"Every" makes sure that the mixture components are separated, and "matrices" is the plural of matrix.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand correctly, you have the following:

Matrix A: the numbers.
Matrix B: the letters.
Matrix C: mixture component #1.
Matrix D: mixture component #2.

---

If this is correct, then it might make more sense to restructure the sentence.

It's tricky to express completely clearly, but I suggest something like this:

> Each matrix exclusively stores one of: the numbers, the letters, or an individual mixture component.

---

If I'm mistaken, it could be the following that you have:

Matrix A: mixture component #1, with some numbers and letters.
Matrix B: mixture component #2, with some numbers and letters.

If so, I suggest the following:

> Each individual mixture component is stored in its own matrix, along with its numbers and letters.